# How to remove line with certain pattern and append it to previous one | Notepad++

Tags: csv, notepad++

I have a CSV file with "|" delimeter but it has a bug and I want to correct it as a Hot Fix, before to get in the code, as it contains a lot of lines is hard to do it manually.

CSV example:

```
Michael|Cort
| 23
George|Dieter
| 25
```

As you can see the age is displayed in new line, but I want to remove it and put it like this:

```
Michael|Cort| 23
George|Dieter| 25
```

i used regex search with `^\|`

Is this possible? if so, how could let notepad++ remove or backspace to append it to the previous line?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(\|)`
- Replace with: `$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R      : any kind of linebreak (ie. \r, \n, \r\n)
(\|)    : group 1, a pipe character
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          : content of group 1 (i.e. pipe)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Michael|Cort| 23
George|Dieter| 25
```